# how to enable full site accelaration from varnish

Tags: nginx, varnish, varnish-vcl, varnish-4

I am using Varnish  4.0.3 and want to cache my complete website (except some/admin pages) on varnish. To achieve it, I have below questions:-

1. How can I warm up varnish cache
2. Full site acceleration on Varnish
3. How to handle, if back-end down
4. How to configure varnish for below architecture

Architecture: AWS CloudFront (CDN) -> Varnish -> NginX (reverse-proxy) -> NginX -> Drupal

Answer (score 0):

1. write simple crawler
2. don't understand
3. https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleGrace